# How to pass parameter through UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

i have to classes:
existUserView and existUserCustomCell.

the code in existUserView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ExistUserCustomCell *cell = (ExistUserCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExistUserCustomCell"];

    KidManager *kid = [self.kidsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.kidName.text = kid.firstName;
    if([kid.inside isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        cell.kidStatus. text = @"some string";
    }else{
        cell.kidStatus.text = @"some string";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

code in existUserCustomCell:

```
- (IBAction)reportMissing:(id)sender {

}

- (IBAction)callTeacher:(id)sender {

}
```

i need to pass data from 'existUserView' to both button function in 'existUserCustomCell' and to know the row when i press them.
how can i do that the best way?

Comment: Why do you need the cell to know its row? That's rarely needed, if ever.

Comment: its a custom cell that im handling in different class..

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass data from the view controller to the cell, add a property (or two, or three) to the cell class. Set the property when you setup the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Then you cell's methods (including the button handlers) have access to the data as needed.

Add a property to your cell class:

```
@interface ExistUserCustomCell : UITableViewCell

// add this to anything you have
@property (nonatomic, strong) KindManager *kid;

@end
```

Now your button methods have access:

```
- (IBAction)reportMissing:(id)sender {
    // access self.kid to get data
    // anything else you need
}
```

Then in the table view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ExistUserCustomCell *cell = (ExistUserCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExistUserCustomCell"];

    KidManager *kid = [self.kidsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.kid = kid;
    cell.kidName.text = kid.firstName;
    if([kid.inside isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        cell.kidStatus. text = @"some string";
    }else{
        cell.kidStatus.text = @"some string";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I'm guessing that it is the `KidManager` data that you need in the cell. Adjust as needed.

BTW - if my guess is correct then the cell should set itself up with the data instead of having the logic in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: im sorry, i new to ios develop. as i said, i have 2 classes.
one handling the table view and the second handling the tableview cell(custom cell).
i have 2 buttons on the cell so the IBAction in the custom cell class.
i need to pass data to the IBAction functions respectively to the cell indexPath. how can i do that?

Comment: I already told you how. If you add a property for the data on the cell class then the button methods in the cell have access to the data. See my updated answer with more details.